# Arranging set A and B to maximize their power

Tags: combinatorics, exponentiation

Given two sets A and B each with $n$ positive reals.

How to arrange elements in A and B such that

$$\prod_{i=1}^n a_i^{b_i}$$

is maximized?

Will ascending order of A and B make the correct answer? Please explain.

Comment: I guess you mean a product, like $$\prod_{i=1}^n a_i^{b_i}$$

Comment: I edited it. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @martycohen yes. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $a_1\lt a_2$ and $b_1\lt b_2$ then
$$
\frac{a_1^{b_1}a_2^{b_2}}{a_1^{b_2}a_2^{b_1}}=\left(\frac{a_2}{a_1}\right)^{b_2-b_1}\gt1
$$
Thus, simply matching the order of two elements that are out of order with each other makes the product bigger. This implies that if both are sorted in the same order, the product is maximized (otherwise, switch any two that are out of order with each other, and the product increases). Therefore, you are correct.

Comment: This is essentially how the rearrangement inequality is proved.

Comment: I imagine something like $(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)-(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)=(a_2-a_1)(b_2-b_1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$P = \prod_{i=1}^n a_i^{b_i}
$
and
$p = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \ln a_i
$
where
the $a_i$
is a non-decreasing sequence.
We want the arrangement of
the $b_i$
which maximizes $P$.

Maximizing $P$
is the same as maximizing $p$.

Then Chebychev's inequality
(this one:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality)
says that $p$ is max when
the $b_i$ are non-decreasing
and min when
the $b_i$ are non-increasing.

So your conjecture is correct.

Comment: The rearrangement inequality is useful in many circumstances (+1)